# Show ACF field in Woocommerce order

Tags: plugins

I have a couple of ACF fields for my products, mainly dropdowns. However, they will no be considered in Woocommerce order.

So let's say the user picked "Choice 1"  from a "Select choice" ACF field (it does not interfere with the price), this should be added in the order that will be created.

I found this article but there's no code actually. Thank you for you insights

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675101/display-advanced-custom-fields-value-in-woocommerce-order-details-and-all-emails/59355471#59355471